# How to read a value between two words in an external text file using php

Tags: php, file

I'm looking for a way to fetch a value from a txt file using php. This function need to be flexible so i'm thinking it's best to make it read the value that's between two words in the file. How can this be done? An example is this [file](http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/3-day-forecast.txt) where i need the number between "is" and "(below" from the line that starts with The greatest expected 3 hr Kp for[...].

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whether this is what you want:

```
<?php
  $myfile = fopen("http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/3-day-forecast.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

  while (!feof( $myfile )) {
    $row = fgets($myfile,128);

    // find the row
    $thegreatest = strpos( $row,"The greatest expected 3 hr Kp");
    if( $thegreatest !== false ){

      echo $row."<br>";

      $words = explode(" ", $row);
      $pos = array_search("(below", $words, true);

      // the result
      $value = $words[ $pos-1 ];      
      echo $value;

    }
  }

  fclose($myfile);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting the value I need, but how to I remove the line "The greatest expected 3 hr Kp for Jan 28-Jan 30 2018 is 3" (below NOAA from the result? I only need the value.

Comment: I got it. I just removed this line:
echo $row."<br>";

Comment: Why is my post getting downvoted? I'd appreciate if the voters told me what was wrong with the question.

Comment: Maybe they hope you try it first, and then show your work that is get stuck